# Yii PHP Recoverable error

Tags: php, yii

I'm use Yii PHP framework but i cant write this code, what's the true ?

```
<?php 
if ( Yii::app()->user->isGuest != 1 ){ 
$guest =  "<div class='box admin'>" .
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.CPortlet', array(
            'title'=>'Admin menu',
        ));
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
            'items'=>$this->menu,
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'operations'),
        ));
        $this->endWidget();

"</div>";
}
 else { $guest = ""; };
?>

<?php

echo $guest;

?>
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
Recoverable error
```

Comment: i need add $this->beginWidget in the $guest

Comment: I think this is a real question, maybe not in the very best English. But the method beginWidet() and endWidget() are echoing a string, therefore there are problems with the code which are not totally obvious. It would be a solution to call ob_start() and ob_get_clean() together with echos of the strings to get the content of a widget. Sadly I can't post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just remove used this code without variables and i rewrite code in the place

```
<?php 
if ( Yii::app()->user->isGuest != 1 ){ 
  echo '<div class="box admin">';
    $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.CPortlet', array(
      'title'=>'Admin menu',
    ));
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
      'items'=>$this->menu,
      'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'operations'),
    ));
    $this->endWidget();
    echo '</div>';
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a semicolon at the end of this line:

```
$guest =  "<div class='box admin'>"
```

Comment: Well now this answer doesn't make sense after OP made an edit to his code. Even with the edit though, what is the random quote for? `$guest =  "<div class='box admin'>"' .`

Answer (score 1):

I'm only guessing here but this code may work:

```
<?php 
if ( Yii::app()->user->isGuest != 1 ){ 
  $guest = '<div class="box admin">'
    . $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.CPortlet', array(
      'title'=>'Admin menu',
    ))
    . $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
      'items'=>$this->menu,
      'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'operations'),
    ))
    . $this->endWidget()
    . '</div>';
}
else
  $guest = '';
?>

<?php

echo $guest;

?>
```

Comment: @Abudayah  What's the return value of the widget methods? is it strings?

Comment: I've never used Yii, but I know with Zend Framework a lot of times methods will return a reference to $this so you can do method chaining. Something like `$this->beginWidget(...)->widget(...)->endWidget(...);`

Comment: I Think (Object of class CPortlet could not be converted to string )